# redirect user in IIS7 between two folders depending on IP mask

Tags: iis, server, iis-7

Suppose I have `Default Web Site` and folders in it.

Roughly, the tree would look like this:

```
|- Server
    |- Default Web Site
        |- folder1
        |- folder2
```

I want to redirect the user to different folders in my website depending on their IP mask.

For example if the user's IP has a pattern of:

```
- 10.10.10.* IIS has to redirect to "folder1"
- 11.11.11.* IIS has to redirect to "folder2"
```

Is this possible? If so, then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <rule name="RedirectBySourceIP1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="10.10.10.(.*)" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="folder1(.*)" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="/folder1" />
            </rule>
 <rule name="RedirectBySourceIP2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="11.11.11.(.*)" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="folder2(.*)" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="/folder2" />
            </rule>
```